# why would a pdb ID generate 2 templates that are identical

Tags: sequence-homology

I used the sequence of a protein kinase to generate templates for another and build a homology model using these templates using swiss-model online tool. there are 2 templates that were generated using the same pdb ID and I cannot find a reason as to why this happened, they are identical in all aspects and the homology models generated were also identical with no variance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please write down in your question all the passages you did starting from here: https://swissmodel.expasy.org/interactive

Comment: have you read the documentation ? https://swissmodel.expasy.org/docs/help apparently templated are not generated but found given your input , what does 'The Template Results page' serves to you ??

Comment: What is the sequence that you used? What templates were produced?